# Check which column a UICollectionView Cell is in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollection View and am creating a custom animation when a user taps on a cell.

There are three columns in the collection view. Is there a quick way to figure out, given a index path, the column that was tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single section, you can just use modulo arithmetic on the `item` of the index path.

```
let column = indexPath.item % 3  // gives a value from 0 to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Assuming you setup the columns as sections in the collection view, you should just be able to check the section of the indexpath.

An IndexPath is primarily made of two parts, a row, and a section.  If you have 3 sections than `indexPath.section == 0` is the first column, `indexPath.section == 1` is the second, and `indexPath.section == 2` is the third